# Changing Encoding while Xml.parse() with SaxFeedParser Java

Tags: java, android, encoding

I am trying to load hebrew rss using the fllow :

Xml.parse(_InputStream,  Xml.Encoding.ISO_8859_1 , root.getContentHandler());

taken from ibm site :
[link text](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-android/)

I would like to use other Encoding like "ISO8859_8" rather than :

Xml.Encoding.ISO_8859_1,

Xml.Encoding.US_ASCII,

Xml.Encoding.UTF_16,

Xml.Encoding.UTF_8

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can't, because Xml.Encoding is an enum. you'll have to use one of the other methods, or -- if you can -- get the RSS feed producer to output UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks, 
I want back to XML DOM method that solve my problem.

Comment: how can i encode the tag content of xml in DOM parsing,i'm using DOM feed parser.where xml file have hexadecimal content in addition to string but i need it to original text.please help me